# Deploying Rails application: Permission denied - /root/.gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I'm trying to deploy my Rails 3 application to real environment (Apache+Passenger).

However, I got the following error:

```
Permission denied - /root/.gems
```

Any ideas ?

And one more (probably stupid) question: Do I need to run `rails server` in the real environment, like I do in the development one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using passenger, you don't need to use Rails' server.

As far as your initial question, it sounds like you installed rubygems with `sudo`. The gem path is in the root directory. I'd recommend going through the gems installation again as a normal user, not root.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer that solved this for me.

http://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-128920.html